# UK Immigration: Can you switch from Youth Mobility to a student visa?

Tags: visas, uk, study, england

I'm planning to move to the UK under the Youth Mobility visa. The plan is to work for the first year then in the second year, start studying a 3-year degree. So I need to be in the UK for 4 years in total.

Is it possible to switch form my Youth Mobility visa to a student visa when my 2-year limit runs out for my Youth Mobility visa?

Answer (score 2):

No, it is not possible to switch from Tier 5 to Tier 4. [From the UK government's webpage on the subject](https://www.gov.uk/tier-4-general-visa/switch-to-this-visa):

> You may be able to change (switch) to a Tier 4 (General) student visa if you’re in the UK under any of the following visas or schemes:
>
> - Tier 2 (General)
> - Tier 2 (Intra-company transfer)
> - Tier 2 (Minister of religion)
> - Tier 4 (Child)

Since this won't apply to you, you can't switch to Tier 4.

It's also not possible to extend a Tier 5 (Youth mobility) visa. Therefore, you will need to leave the UK in order to apply for a Tier 4 visa when your Tier 5 visa expires.